# How do I create and populate a mongodb database using a script

Tags: jquery, angularjs, mongodb, playframework-2.2

I had created an web application using Play Framework, MongoDB, AngularJS, Bootsrap and  jquery. I want to create and populate the database (ex: student database) using the script (ex: script.js).

Comment: Best of luck. Sort of surprised you haven't gotten slammed with downvotes. What, precisely, have you TRIED? We're here to help when things get broke, or when you get stuck.

Comment: Please visit the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) center to see what and how to ask. HINT: show effort and code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I want to create and populate the database using scripting file (.js). So I'm stuck in there.